# Force whatsapp to upload backup

Tags: backup

My whatsapp is uploading backup every week so the backup system is working .

But i want to backup the chat right now so i tried to press the big green "BACK UP" button. A pop up appeared "Backing up messages , please wait a moment (%)" .

It goes from 0% to 100% , but after 100% , the popup just disappear and no backup was made .

How do i force whatsapp to upload backup right now ?

---

I log out from my whatsapp account and relogin , the back up button works after relogin . I don't know why this happen , maybe a bug in whatsapp.

Answer (score 0):

By backup do you mean backup to Google Drive or local backup of messages?

The Whatsapp backup process consists of two distinct phases:

- **Local backup**: saving all messages inside the phone memory.
- **Backup to Google Drive**: it happens only after the local backup and only if a Google account is selected. This backup includes all messages and media (you can choose whether to include videos or not).

If you get a pop-up saying: "Backing up messages", it means that it's only completing the local backup of messages, which seems to be successful in your case.

If you want to force a backup to Google Drive you have to first select the Google account in Settings > Chat > Chat Backup > Google Drive Settings > Google Account, then click the green "Back Up" button and Whatsapp will automatically backup both locally and to Google Drive.